# how to remove the row of the table containing textbox by clicking the respective remove button

Tags: angularjs

I have an add button which adds the row containing texbox. However I want to remove the row of the table by clicking the respective remove button.
The view page code is like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>showintable</title>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/controller/checkCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/filter/filterrange.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="sayCtrl">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>S. No.</th>
                <th>Textbox1</th>
                <th>Texbox2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="v in [] | range:tellrange">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="Namemodel[$index]" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="Addressmodel[$index]" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" ng-click="subtractrow()" value="Remove" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td align="right" colspan="4"><input ng-click="addrow()" type="button" value="Add" /></td></tr>
        </table> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller checkCtrl.js of angularjs is like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']).controller('sayCtrl', SayController);
SayController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
function SayController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.Namemodel = [];
    $scope.Addressmodel = [];
    $scope.tellrange = 1;
    $scope.addrow = function () {
        $scope.tellrange = $scope.tellrange + 1;
    };
    $scope.subtractrow = function () {

    };
}
```

The filter filterrange.js of angularjs is like this:

```
angular.module('app').filter('range', function () {
    return function (input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total);

        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            input.push(i);
        }

        return input;
    };
});
```

The page looks like this:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ZNi-QTxOOYUjNqcnlraDVydVE

I have searched for it but I could not get the relevant answer. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make it easier to iterate through the rows. You want N rows, and each row should have two pieces of information: a name and an address.

So don't use two arrays. Use **one** array, of rows, where each row has a name and an address:

```
$scope.rows = [
  {
    name: 'name 1',
    address: 'address 1'
  },
  {
    name: 'name 2',
    address: 'address 2'
  }
];
```

To add a row, all you need is

```
$scope.rows.push({
  name: '',
  address: ''
});
```

To iterate on the rows, all you need is

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="row.name" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="row.address" /></td>
  <td><input type="button" ng-click="removeRow(row)" value="Remove" /></td>
</tr>
```

As you see, you need to pass **what** row to remove in your removeRow function.

And to remove the row, all you need is to find its index in $scope.rows, and remove that index:

```
$scope.removeRow = function(row) {
  var index = $scope.rows.indexOf(row);
  $scope.rows.splice(index, 1);
}
```

I don't know exactly what each row is supposed to represent. I guess it might be a user, for example, so feel free to rename rows to users, and row to user. Naming things, and having a good, correct model, is the key. Your page displays a table of users. Not two tables of names and addresses.